# Check if a PNG image contains (semi) transparent pixel using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing, png, pixel, transparent

I want to use AS3 to check a (32-bit ARGB) PNG image to see if it contains any (semi) transparent pixel (returning `true` or `false`). What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: How do you have access to this image? Are you loading it by a Loader?

Comment: The image file is on my HDD and I can access it locally via Loader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A long time ago I was looking for the same thing and I tried using loops to check for each pixel. But that took **a lot** of time and consumed incredible amount of CPU. Luckily we have the [`BitmapData.compare()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29) method, which outputs a Bitmapdata if there are any diferences in compared BitmapData objects.

Also there's the [`BitmapData.transparent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#transparent) property, which actually directly gives you the answer as a Boolean. But I have never used it directly on a loaded image myself.

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Point;

var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('someImage.png');
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,imgLoaded);
ldr.load(req);

function imgLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var l:Loader = e.target.loader,
    bmp:Bitmap = l.content as Bitmap,
    file:String = l.contentLoaderInfo.url.match(/[^\/\\]+$/)[0];
    trace(bmp.bitmapData.transparent);
    // I think this default property should do it but
    // in case it does not, here's another approach:
    var trans:Boolean = isTransparent(bmp.bitmapData);
    trace(file,'is'+(trans ? '' : ' not'),'transparent');
}

function isTransparent(bmpD:BitmapData):Boolean {
    var dummy:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bmpD.width,bmpD.height,false,0xFF6600);
    // create a BitmapData with the size of the source BitmapData
    // painted in a color (I picked orange)
    dummy.copyPixels(bmpD,dummy.rect,new Point());
    // copy pixels of the original image onto this orange BitmapData
    var diffBmpD:BitmapData = bmpD.compare(dummy) as BitmapData;
    // this will return null if both BitmapData objects are identical
    // or a BitmapData otherwise
    return diffBmpD != null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Both of your methods work great on my test!

Comment: This is... elegant. I like it. How is the speed compared to the pixel-by-pixel approach I posted?

Comment: @inhan `BitmapData.transparent` is the fastest solution so far but sometimes it fails to detect opaque images saved from Photoshop, like [this one](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/7NBwYNS/0/blob?download)

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 I did several tests with some large PNG images (2-8MB in size) and both of @inhan's methods works real fast. Relatively, pixel-to-pixel method works much slower but surprisingly good to my expectation. 

FYI, on one test, `BitmapData.transparent` works in 14ms, `BitmapData.compare()` works in 30ms and pixel-to-pixel method works in 590ms. (My CPU is an Intel Core i7-2600K @3.4Ghz.)

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 thanks. I did not have the chance to compare all the methods but apparently Hoang posted his.

Comment: @HoangHuynh I saved several PNG images in PHS via Save For Web. I thought it embedded the transparency information in the file only when it has transparent pixels and the 'transparent' checkbox is selected (at least this is what it did to the images I tried to save that way). It's interesting, though, that this image you provided is not transparent at all yet it has the transparency value set to true in its internal data.

Comment: @inhan Yes apparently Photoshop saves the transparency information correctly if you use the _Save For Web_ command. However, if you save the PNG with _File > Save As_ command, the transparency value seems to be set to `true` even though the image is opaque.

Comment: @HoangHuynh Oh yeah I totally ignored that option. That explains it. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the benchmarks @HoangHuynh . I'll have to use this method in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Only way I know of doing it is manually, unfortunately. There may be a built in way of doing it, but my guess is it would use the same method described below

```
var bytes:ByteArray = ( loader.content as Bitmap ).bitmapData.getPixels(); //that getter may be incorrect. I'd verify the property names are correct first
var bLength:Number = bytes.length; //you'll gain considerable speed by saving the length to memory rather than accessing it repeatedly
for ( var i:Number = 0; i < bLength; i++ ) {
    var alpha:uint = bytes[i] >> 24 & 255;
    if ( alpha > 0 && alpha < 255 ) {
        //put code in here that will run if it is semi transparent
    }
    if ( alpha == 255 ) {
        //put code in here that will run if it is entirely opaque
    }
    if ( alpha == 0 ) {
        //put code in here that will run if it is entirely transparent
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `ByteArray` will have 32 bits (or 4 bytes (8 bits per byte)) of data for each individual pixel. After the loop is finished, you should definitely do a `bytes.clear();` for memory sake and you should also `break;` the loop the second you hit what you want (otherwise it will keep running until it checks each and every pixel in your image. A 256x256 image will run 65,536 times, for comparison's sake).

Just for clarity:

- RGBA/ARGB is measured with values 0-255
- 0 is black (0x000000), 255 is white (0xffffff)
- The blacker the alpha byte, the more transparent it is
- We use simple bitwise shifts to get the actual value of that byte (bits 24-32) and set it to a value between 0 and 255
- You can also do this for RGB channels. B is `>> 0 & 255`, G is `>> 8 & 255`, and R is `>> 16 & 255`

Comment: I think you have the value for transparency backwards - an alpha value of 255 is fully opaque and 0 is fully transparent.

Comment: This will take such a long time. I remember trying this method and waiting for about a minute some time ago.

Comment: @MarkRansom Now that I think about it, you're right. I'll update my answer right now.

Comment: but does a png with NO transparency retain the alpha channel? my bet is that it can have, but 'clever' software would remove that on save. so, maybe checking if there is an alpha channel might be enough to tell that there is a transparency.

Comment: @inhan It does. This method killed a project for me back in May. It is not a quick method. If the Asker is only doing it once at startup or something, though, it shouldn't be an issue. They could also cheat and resize the `BitmapData` to be something smaller (say 25% or 50%). There will be less data and the results will be less accurate, but transparency wouldn't be entirely lost so it should still work

Comment: @joe It does not matter what the PNG is. Flash reads a bitmap as a field of pixels with 32 bits in the RGBA format when using the `getPixels()` method I used in my answer

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3: Thank you for the answer! I think the getter should be:

 `var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, loader.width, loader.height);

 var bytes:ByteArray = (loader.content as Bitmap).bitmapData.getPixels(rect);`

Also, `var alpha:uint = bytes[i] >> 24 & 255;` seems to always return 0 for me, I am checking on that.

Comment: @HoangHuynh Make sure you use `loader.loaderInfo.height/width` instead of just `loader.height/width`. `Loader`'s height/width properties can change, but `LoaderInfo`'s will always match the original.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do that.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 the `bytes:ByteArray` does not to store the data for each pixel in a 32-bit element. Instead, it consists of 4 arrays of byte (each element is 8-bit). `bytes[0]` stores the alpha value (0-255) of first pixel, `bytes[1]` the red value of first pixel, `bytes[2]` green and `bytes[3]` blue. `bytes[4]` is the alpha value of second pixel, and so on. So your loop should be: `for ( var i:Number = 0; i < bLength; i+=4 ) { var alpha:uint = bytes[i]; // the rest of your loop }`

Comment: According to this little research (http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/10/13/case-study-actionscript-3-performance-optimization/) loop over vectors are 4-5 times faster.